# C# & SQL Server : code running in SQL Server but not in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an extremely weird issue. I have a SQL command that runs fine if used directly in SQL Server, but with C# it returns no table. I am using this in a BGW..

This is the code:

```
private void BackgroundWorker2DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    try 
    {
        if(sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
            sqlConnection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception c)  
    {
         pause=true; 
         MessageBox.Show(c.toString()); 
         Application.Exit();
    }

    try
    { 
        DataSet SetBW = new DataSet();  
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(); 

        int unixStart = 0;

        if(realtime) unixStart = (Int32)
            (System.DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(origin)).TotalSeconds;
        else 
            unixStart = unixBegin;

        //get all users from departments
        string sqlString = "SELECT e.nUserID, e.state, e.nDateTime, u.sUserName FROM tb_event_log e, tb_user u "; 
        sqlString +=" WHERE e.nUserID = u.sUserID AND (e.state like 'present%' OR e.state like 'absent%') AND u.nDepartmentIdn="+idDep+" AND e.nDateTime between "+unixStart+" and "+unixEnd+" ORDER BY nEventLogIdn DESC";

        // for getting the sqlQuery
        if(textBox1.InvokeRequired) 
           textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate(){textBox1.Text = sqlString;});

        int count = 0;

        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection); 
        dataAdapter.Fill(SetBW);

        if(SetBW.Tables.Count > 0) 
            MessageBox.Show("sssss");
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("0 table");
}
```

I don't get what I'm missing.

P.S: BGW is `RunWorkerAsync()` and realtime is true. I am getting this error on an older 1GB, XP running machine. This does not happen on Win8 (probably for Win7 either)

Comment: Use Command Parameters.

Comment: Does it work on the main thread?

Comment: @Douglas Zare: I tried using this piece of code in a separate, test solution, still in BW, and it worked. I guess in main would work..

Comment: What's `sqlConnection`? And you should be returning results in `RunWorkerCompleted`, not from `BackgroundWorker2DoWork`.

Comment: Did you miss to set the unixEnd variable?

Comment: @Dour High Arch: the sqlConnection=new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BioStar;Data Source=localhost\\BSSERVER; connection timeout=1"); The result is not going to WorkerCompleted because the result is proccesed and then returned. I did not inlcude that since I thought it has little importance for the question..

Comment: @Steve: No, it seems to pass fine. String turns out: "e.nDateTime between 1427068800 and 1427155200".

Comment: Whats the **ERROR?!** *ps best to use* `using` statements.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: It simply return no table. so SetBW.Tables.Count==0 and trying any SetBW.Tables[0].Rows.. turns into a "there is no table 0" error

Comment: Double check the connection string points to the correct database. Run a SQLProfile trace on the SQL Server when running the code on the PC that doesn't return data.

Comment: I might be blind but the SQL Profiler doesn't seem to be included in MSSQL Server Management Studio Express.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Better use string.format, something like:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT e.nUserID, e.state, e.nDateTime, u.sUserName FROM tb_event_log e, tb_user u WHERE e.nUserID=u.sUserID AND (e.state like 'present%' OR e.state like 'absent%') AND u.nDepartmentIdn {0} AND e.nDateTime between {1} and {2} ORDER BY nEventLogIdn DESC", idDep, unixStart, unixEnd);
```

Edit: I've not tested this, but  remember that in some point I got some errors using + creating some query.

Comment: Maybe not, of course is better using CommandParameters, but I remember that in some point, I got some errors creating the string with + on it and not with string.format. But maybe you are right. I will add that is untested.

Comment: Its PC specific so its not likely the code or the concatenated SQL query, its more likely a environmental or configuration issue.

Comment: mmm, I was thinking about the connection.. but he is opening the connection in the beginning.. so... no error means connection opened successfully. so.. any ideas Jeremy?

Comment: I suggested conn string works but may point to different dBs and also asked OP to run SQL profiler which should shed light on the root cause

Comment: Weird. It says string does not contain a definition for format. I guess this is used only in Console Applications?

Comment: Eddited. Format with F

Comment: Tried it.. seems to not influence the result. Let me play around a bit with the conditions and see if anything triggers something..

Comment: The stupid machine wasn't probably always building my changes. After I modified it was still showing older code. Cleaned the solution and rewrote each condition step by step, seems to go on now.. Ty for all reply's. Careful when using junk machines..

Answer (score 0):

As per OP:

The machine wasn't probably building the changes and after modifying was still showing older code.

Cleaning the solution and rewriting each condition step by step resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Safest that I know is put your variables in a SqlCommand Parameter

```
    string sqlString = "SELECT e.nUserID, e.state, e.nDateTime, u.sUserName FROM tb_event_log e, tb_user u "; 
    sqlString +=" WHERE e.nUserID=u.sUserID AND (e.state like 'present%' OR e.state like 'absent%') AND u.nDepartmentIdn=@idDep AND e.nDateTime between @unixStart and @unixEnd ORDER BY nEventLogIdn DESC";

SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sqlString,sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idDep", idDep);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unixStart ", unixStart );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unixEnd ", unixEnd );
```

Comment: Did you try by the way tracing it, so you can capture the value of `sqlString` ?